How do I keep textures the same size on different objects?
Q: How do I keep textures the same size on different objects?
I want the red texture to be the same size as the green texture, even though they're on different objects.



that's what uv editing/map is for...

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

@HarryMcKenzie This is my file I have been using a texel density add-on also and it did kinda look like for both of them the first 2 but the large one is still not in the same size. File =>  https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZBoPmv06

@HarryMcKenzie Hello  sorry for not saying it back in the first comment.

Make uv map to square uv map => Blender UV's Follow Active Quad

You can convert your NURBS to meshes(Object -> Convert menu in the 3d viewport header) and UV unwrap them together. They can remain separate objects, just enter edit mode with all of them selected, select all and hit  U  for UV mapping menu and choose Unwrap. Seams may need to be set from the same menu with edges you want as seams selected before unwrapping. Unwrap will attempt to keep scale of different UV islands similar. You may need to move and scale them to match your image texture.

If you have bent forms that give you bent UV islands but have uniform quad geometry following the forms, UV Squares add-on may be helpful to straighten them out.
Alternatively, you may scale the texture space of NURBS objects, but that may be a bit less convenient.

